# How can I unset an array which contains a unique value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
<?php
$input = [
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Peter"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"John"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Ali"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Jack"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Martin"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Barmar"],
    ["From"=>"Peter", "To"=>"John"]
];
$output = [];

array_walk($input, function($element) use (&$output) {
    $output[$element['From']][] = $element;
});

print_r(array_values($output));

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => Peter
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => John
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => Ali
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => Barmar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Ali
                    [To] => Jack
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Ali
                    [To] => Martin
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Peter
                    [To] => John
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to remove the whole array when the valye of `To` key is unique *(not exists as value of neither `From` and `To` keys)*. So this is expected result: *(`barmar` and `martin` and unique, so their arrays should be removed)*

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => Peter
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => John
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Jack
                    [To] => Ali
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Ali
                    [To] => Jack
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [From] => Peter
                    [To] => John
                )

        )

)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I would perform the check of uniqueness before starting the array_walk

Comment: @RST how exactly do you mean??

Answer (score 0):

push all value in single array then count its elements. If count >1 then only push value to output. Try this:

```
$input = [
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Peter"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"John"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Ali"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Jack"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Martin"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Barmar"],
    ["From"=>"Peter", "To"=>"John"]
];

$exist_array=array();
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {        
      array_push($exist_array, $value1);
  }
}

$vals = array_count_values($exist_array);

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($element) use (&$output,$vals) {  
  if($vals[$element['To']] > 1)
    $output[$element['From']][] = $element;
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($output));
```

check result here:

https://eval.in/736562

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

echo ('<pre>');

$input = [
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Peter"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"John"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Ali"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Jack"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Martin"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Barmar"],
    ["From"=>"Peter", "To"=>"John"]
];

$input = array_filter($input, function($from_to) use ($input) {

    foreach ($input as $item) {

        if ($item == $from_to)
            continue;

        if (in_array($from_to['To'], $item, true))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
});

$output = [];

array_walk($input, function($element) use (&$output) {
    $output[$element['From']][] = $element;
});

print_r(array_values($output));
```

Answer (score 0):

Count occurance for each name, then check the values of `$input` names with count 1. The `$output` array will be your start point for the array_walk

```
$input = [
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Peter"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"John"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Ali"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Jack"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Martin"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Barmar"],
    ["From"=>"Peter", "To"=>"John"]
];

$unique = array();
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $entrie => $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value ) {

    if (! isset($unique[$value])) {
        $unique[$value]= 1 ;
    } else { 
        $unique[$value]++ ;
    }
   }
}    

foreach ($input as $entrie => $row) {
      if ( $unique[$row['From']] != 1 && $unique[$row['To']] != 1 )
          $output[] = $row;
}

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php

$input = [
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Peter"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"John"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Ali"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Jack"],
    ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Martin"],
    ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Barmar"],
    ["From"=>"Peter", "To"=>"John"]
];

$removeUnique = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input)),FALSE);
$removeUnique = (array_unique(array_diff_assoc($removeUnique, array_unique($removeUnique))));

$output = [];

array_walk($input, function($element) use (&$output,$removeUnique) {

    if(in_array($element['From'], $removeUnique) && in_array($element['To'], $removeUnique) ){
        $output[$element['From']][] = $element;
    }
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($output));
```

Reference Link :

https://eval.in/736619

Answer (score 0):

> @stack try this one :

```
<?php
    $input = [
        ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Peter"],
        ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"John"],
        ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Ali"],
        ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Jack"],
        ["From"=>"Ali", "To"=>"Martin"],
        ["From"=>"Jack", "To"=>"Barmar"],
        ["From"=>"Peter", "To"=>"John"]
    ];
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($input); // array before
    $to = [];
    foreach($input as $key => $val){
        if(in_array($val["To"], $to)){
            unset($input[$key]);
        }       
        $to[] = $val["To"];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array_values($input));// array after
```